# Unpair Bluetooth device not working in redmi phones, Used "removeBond" this method working in all other device

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, redmi-device

Consider:

```
fun BluetoothDevice.removeBond() {
try {
    javaClass.getMethod("removeBond").invoke(this)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.i("Removing bond has been failed. ${e.message}")
} }
```

In another Android phone this method is working well, but it is not working in [Redmi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redmi) phones.

#### Logs

1610017762.258 ? I/BluetoothDevice: removeBond() for device #### called by pid: 2027 tid: 2027

1610017762.268 ? E/BluetoothUtils: checkCallerAllowedToTouchBondDevices: the BT device is attached to 1000, can't be touched by 10211

1610017762.268 ? W/BluetoothAdapterService: removeBond() - Not allowed ownerUid to remove bond unless callerUid is system uid.

Comment: I have he same :(

Comment: i have same issue